# Python - Print multiple list in one line

Tags: list

I have 4 lists with random data and I want to print them as a table

Example (This is not what I want to print)

```
list1 = [data01,data02,data03]
list2 = [data04,data05,data06]
list3 = [data07,data08,data09]
list4 = [data10,data11,data12]
```

when i try the following

```
print ("\n").join(list1)+'*'.join(list2)+'*'.join(list3)+"*".join(list4)
```

I get

```
data01data04data07data10
data02data05data08data11
data03data06data09data12
```

I'm trying to have them like

```
data01  *  data04  *  data07  *  data10
data02  *  data05  *  data08  *  data11
data03  *  data06  *  data09  *  data12
```

Python 2.7.12

Thanks!